# discord.py bot connecting to voice channel but OpusNotLoaded, and problems with discord.opus.load_opus()

Tags: python, discord.py, opus

I'm trying to connect my bot to a voice channel and then playing an mp3 file.
This was my original code :

```
@client.command(name='voice', case_insensitive=True)
async def voice(context):

    channel = context.author.voice.channel

    await channel.connect()

    guild = context.guild
    voice_client: discord.VoiceClient = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=guild)

    voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('voices/bonjour.mp3', executable='/Users/rimelmallah/Desktop/Python/ffmpeg'), after=None)
```

I got this error : `discord.opus.OpusNotLoaded`

So I added this line of code before the last line : `discord.opus.load_opus()`
When i did this I got this error : `TypeError: load_opus() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'`

So I tried to modify my line of code to : `discord.opus.load_opus('opus')`
And this time I got the following error : `OSError: dlopen(opus, 6): image not found`

I tried to install Opus from this link : https://opus-codec.org/release/stable/2019/04/12/libopus-1_3_1.html
but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#opus-library) say that `name` is `The filename of the shared library.`. You will have to give the function `load_opus()` the exact name, presumably also with file path, if the library isn't located in the same directory as your python-file.

---

The file should be called something like

```
libopus-0-x64.dll
```

However there are some things to look out for. Look at the docs for further information

Comment: I changed the line with : `discord.opus.load_opus('libopus-0.x64.dll')` (this is the name of the file on my mac) but I got another error : `OSError: dlopen(libopus-0.x64.dll, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 libopus-0.x64.dll: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x4D 0x5A 0x90 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00
 /Users/rimelmallah/Desktop/Python/projects/discord_bot/libopus-0.x64.dll: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x4D 0x5A 0x90 0x00 0x03 0x00 0x00 0x00`

Comment: "on my mac" - if you're using a mac, the `.dll` won't be much help to you, since it is Windows only. Make sure you have the opus library installed `python3 -m pip install -U "discord.py[voice]"` and have a look at [this thread](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/783)

Comment: Thank you the thread helped me to understand the issue. I just needed to `brew install opus`